# Puppeteer: wait for request to finish after dropdown selection FILTER

Tags: node.js, filter, puppeteer, dropdown, wait

I'm trying to scrape data off a car sales website. It has several "dropdowns". My problem is that the lists are always filled / complete and when I select the values as make or model the following are filtered, the options can be repeated or different, and I don't know what to wait to know if my list has loaded correctly. If I make my code with timers it works great, but they will be removed. Next I leave a part of my code:

```
const scraperObject = {
url: 'https://www.example.com/cars', 
async scraper(browser){
  ....
  async function getMarcas(page) {
        return await getSelectOptions(page,
        'select#category__l2 > option');
    }

    async function getModelos(page) {
        return await getSelectOptions(page,
        'select#category__l3 > option');
    }

    async function getAnodesde(page) {
        return await getSelectOptions(page,
        'select#year-filter-from > option');
    }

    async function getAnohasta(page) {
        return await getSelectOptions(page,
        'select#year-filter-to > option');
    }
  
  await page.waitForFunction('document.querySelector("#category__l2").length > 0');
  let marcas = await getMarcas(page);
  
  for (const [ i, state ] of marcas.entries()) {
    await page.select('#category__l2', state.value);
    await page.waitForSelector('#category__l3:not(:disabled)');
    let modelos = await getModelos(page);
    
    for (const [ j, state1 ] of modelos.entries()) {
      await page.select('#category__l3', state1.value);
      await page.waitForFunction('document.querySelector("#year-filter-from").length < 29');
      await page.waitForFunction('document.querySelector("#year-filter-to").length < 29');
      let anodesde = await getAnodesde(page);
      let anohasta = await getAnohasta(page);
      
      const desde = await page.evaluate(() => {return document.querySelector('#year-filter-from').length;});
      for (var ii=0;ii<5000;ii++){
        if (desde > 0){
          ii=5001
          }else{
            desde = await page.evaluate(() => {return document.querySelector('#year-filter-from').length;});
          }
      }
      
      const hasta = await page.evaluate(() => {return document.querySelector('#year-filter-to').length;});
            
            for (var iii=0;iii<5000;iii++){
                if (hasta > 0){
                    iiii=5001
                }else{                      
                    hasta = await page.evaluate(() => {return document.querySelector('#year-filter-to').length;});              
                }
            }
      
      for (const [ k, state2 ] of anodesde.entries()) {
        await page.select('#year-filter-from', state2.value);
        await page.select('#year-filter-to', state2.value);
        
        for(var gg=0,len = anohasta.length;gg<=len;gg++){ 
            if (anohasta[gg].name ===state2.name){  
                index = gg;
                console.log('lo encontro en la pos: '+gg);
                var selectedVal2 = await page.$eval("#year-filter-to", selectedValue=> selectedValue.value); 
                for(let g=0;g<5000;g++){
                    if(selectedVal2 ==state2.value){ 
                        g=5001; 
                    }else{ 
                        await console.log(anohasta);
                        await page.select('#year-filter-to', state2.value);
                        selectedVal2 = await page.$eval("#year-filter-to", selectedValue=> selectedValue.value); 
                        await page.waitFor(4000);
                    }
                }
                break;
            }else{
            await console.log ('ERROR');
            }
        }
        await page.click('#root-app > section > form > button');
        
        let scrapedData = [];
        
        ...
```

Beyond the result or the error of my code I would like to know what to expect to know when my "dropdowns" are already FILTERED.
Thank you for taking the time to read and sorry for my English

```
<div class="nav-search-classi-content">

    <div class="nav-search-classi__section">
        
            <label for="category">Categorías</label>
            <select id="category" name="category" class="category-filter" tabindex="10" style="display: block; min-width: 212px;"><option value="MLA1744">Autos y camionetas</option><option value="MLA1763">Motos</option><option value="MLA58254">Camiones</option><option value="MLA1785">Náutica</option><option value="MLA7312">Maquinaria agrícola</option><option value="MLA1745">Autos de colección</option><option value="MLA405183">Maquinaria vial</option><option value="MLA1784">Planes de ahorro</option><option value="MLA80579">Motorhomes</option><option value="MLA93412">Autos chocados y averiados</option><option value="MLA93430">Semirremolques</option><option value="MLA51547">Colectivos</option><option value="MLA1907">Otros vehículos</option></select>
            <select id="category__l2" name="BRAND" class="category-filter category-dynamic" tabindex="11" style="display: block; min-width: 212px;"><option value="">Todas las marcas</option><option value="67695">Alfa Romeo</option><option value="40661">Audi</option><option value="66352">BMW</option><option value="2088960">Baic</option><option value="389167">Changan</option><option value="389168">Chery</option><option value="58955">Chevrolet</option><option value="66395">Chrysler</option><option value="389169">Citroën</option><option value="2103629">DFSK</option><option value="2130485">DS</option><option value="10075">Daihatsu</option><option value="66708">Dodge</option><option value="67781">Fiat</option><option value="66432">Ford</option><option value="396748">Foton</option><option value="389171">Geely</option><option value="60559">Honda</option><option value="1089">Hyundai</option><option value="60648">Isuzu</option><option value="396749">Iveco</option><option value="60395">Jeep</option><option value="374002">Kia</option><option value="380878">Lifan</option><option value="75966">Mercedes-Benz</option><option value="65127">Mini</option><option value="1138">Mitsubishi</option><option value="60505">Nissan</option><option value="60279">Peugeot</option><option value="56870">Porsche</option><option value="2710997">RAM</option><option value="9909">Renault</option><option value="60589">Rover</option><option value="60268">SEAT</option><option value="380886">Shineray</option><option value="38765">Smart</option><option value="60285">Subaru</option><option value="43943">Suzuki</option><option value="60297">Toyota</option><option value="60249">Volkswagen</option><option value="60658">Volvo</option></select>
            <select id="category__l3" name="category__l3" class="category-filter category-dynamic" tabindex="12" disabled="" style="display: block; min-width: 212px;"><option value="">Todos los modelos</option></select>
    </div>

    <div class="nav-search-classi__section">
        
        
            <div class="nav-search-classi__range-filter">
                <select id="price-filter-from" name="price_from" class="range-filter range-filter-from" tabindex="100"><option value="">Precio desde</option><option value="1">Sin precio mínimo</option><option value="650000">$ 650.000</option><option value="1150000">$ 1.150.000</option><option value="1650000">$ 1.650.000</option><option value="2150000">$ 2.150.000</option><option value="2650000">$ 2.650.000</option><option value="3150000">$ 3.150.000</option><option value="3650000">$ 3.650.000</option><option value="4150000">$ 4.150.000</option><option value="4650000">$ 4.650.000</option><option value="5150000">$ 5.150.000</option><option value="5650000">$ 5.650.000</option><option value="6150000">$ 6.150.000</option><option value="6650000">$ 6.650.000</option><option value="7150000">$ 7.150.000</option><option value="7650000">$ 7.650.000</option></select>
                <select id="price-filter-to" name="price_to" class="range-filter range-filter-to" tabindex="101"><option value="">Precio hasta</option><option value="650000">$ 650.000</option><option value="1150000">$ 1.150.000</option><option value="1650000">$ 1.650.000</option><option value="2150000">$ 2.150.000</option><option value="2650000">$ 2.650.000</option><option value="3150000">$ 3.150.000</option><option value="3650000">$ 3.650.000</option><option value="4150000">$ 4.150.000</option><option value="4650000">$ 4.650.000</option><option value="5150000">$ 5.150.000</option><option value="5650000">$ 5.650.000</option><option value="6150000">$ 6.150.000</option><option value="6650000">$ 6.650.000</option><option value="7150000">$ 7.150.000</option><option value="7650000">$ 7.650.000</option><option value="0">Sin precio máximo</option></select>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-search-classi__range-filter">
                <select id="year-filter-from" name="years_from" class="range-filter range-filter-from" tabindex="102"><option value="">Año desde</option><option value="2021">2021</option><option value="2020">2020</option><option value="2019">2019</option><option value="2018">2018</option><option value="2017">2017</option><option value="2016">2016</option><option value="2015">2015</option><option value="2014">2014</option><option value="2013">2013</option><option value="2012">2012</option><option value="2011">2011</option><option value="2010">2010</option><option value="2009">2009</option><option value="2008">2008</option><option value="2007">2007</option><option value="2006">2006</option><option value="2005">2005</option><option value="2004">2004</option><option value="2003">2003</option><option value="2002">2002</option><option value="2001">2001</option><option value="2000">2000</option><option value="1999">1999</option><option value="1998">1998</option><option value="1997">1997</option><option value="1996">1996</option><option value="1995">1995</option><option value="1994">1994</option><option value="1993">1993</option><option value="1992">1992</option><option value="1991">1991</option><option value="1989">1989</option><option value="1988">1988</option><option value="1987">1987</option><option value="1984">1984</option><option value="1981">1981</option><option value="1980">1980</option><option value="1978">1978</option><option value="1974">1974</option><option value="1971">1971</option><option value="1970">1970</option><option value="1968">1968</option></select>
                <select id="year-filter-to" name="years_to" class="range-filter range-filter-to" tabindex="103"><option value="">Año hasta</option><option value="2021">2021</option><option value="2020">2020</option><option value="2019">2019</option><option value="2018">2018</option><option value="2017">2017</option><option value="2016">2016</option><option value="2015">2015</option><option value="2014">2014</option><option value="2013">2013</option><option value="2012">2012</option><option value="2011">2011</option><option value="2010">2010</option><option value="2009">2009</option><option value="2008">2008</option><option value="2007">2007</option><option value="2006">2006</option><option value="2005">2005</option><option value="2004">2004</option><option value="2003">2003</option><option value="2002">2002</option><option value="2001">2001</option><option value="2000">2000</option><option value="1999">1999</option><option value="1998">1998</option><option value="1997">1997</option><option value="1996">1996</option><option value="1995">1995</option><option value="1994">1994</option><option value="1993">1993</option><option value="1992">1992</option><option value="1991">1991</option><option value="1989">1989</option><option value="1988">1988</option><option value="1987">1987</option><option value="1984">1984</option><option value="1981">1981</option><option value="1980">1980</option><option value="1978">1978</option><option value="1974">1974</option><option value="1971">1971</option><option value="1970">1970</option><option value="1968">1968</option></select>
            </div>
        
    </div>
</div>
```

I add html code requested by @Yves Gurcan

Comment: I'm not exactly sure I understand your problem. Could you share a sample of the HTML you are working with to scrape data?

Answer (score 1):

One example you could use is with the `page.waitForTimeout()` function. This will wait a given time in ms before completing the next function. I believe it should work for your issue, however I'm not sure if this is the best practice.

An example code snippet would be:

```js
// Go to page
await page.goto('https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select', { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' });

// Wait for selector
await page.waitForSelector('#cars');

// Make selection
await page.select('#cars', 'volvo');

// Then you can wait a set amount of time (5s in this example)
await page.waitForTimeout(5000)

// Whatever you want to do after
```

I'm not sure how your page is being rendered out but sometimes using `page.waitForSelector()` would work fine and its definitely better practice then `page.waitForTimeout()`.

Comment: This command is useful and it works. Replaces "waitFor (x)". But I think it is not the definitive solution

Comment: @Sebaq3 you can try something like waiting for the array of values for next selector to be greater than 1 (assuming there is initially 1 in the array) and then run the command after that.

Comment: This is not possible as the arrays are loaded from the beginning full and then the options are removed.

Comment: Do you mind showing an example site and I can try and find a solution to your issue?

Comment: Ah I see your problem. It wouldn't be an idea situation but you can use the length of the array for each version to tell when its available. Another option would be to check if that selector contains the value you are trying to select. If it does, great then make the selection. If not wait a second and try again.

Comment: @joshpetit no worries glad I could help!